# HTML shows special character in the wrong order

Tags: html, css, angular, redux, sass

I have a string that I want to display in the HTML.
But if the first character is a special character the HTML displays it in the wrong order.
for example if the string is :

> @test : Twitter

I see it in the browser as:

[image]

I tried to change the direction using SCSS and adding space but still looks the same.
how do I display it correctly?
Thanks for any help :)

edit: 
I'm working with Angular 8 and redux.
I'm creating the string in this selector:

```
const getMediaOutlet = createSelector<InquiryDetailsPartialState, InquiryDetailsState, BasicInfoDictionaryModel>(
getInquiryDetailsState, (state: InquiryDetailsState) => {
    const mediaOutlets: MediaOutletsModel[] = JSON.parse(state.data.mediaOutlets);
    return mediaOutlets && mediaOutlets.length ? {
        titleTranslation: 'INQUIRIES.DETAILS.BASIC_INFO.MEDIA_OUTLETS',
        value: mediaOutlets.map<DictionaryValueModel>(item => {
            return { data:" "+item.text +" : "+ item.typeName } //<- here i build the string ;
        }).filter(source => {
            return source.data && source.data.length;  
        })
    } : { value: [], titleTranslation: '' };
});
```

Comment: How you are trying to display special characters? Your HTML and CSS?

Comment: If have no idea, what the requirement nor the problem is.
Is the example you gave the current or expected behaviour?
What kind of `string` do you have? HTML does not have any datatypes. Are you working with javascript?
What does CSS have to do with it?

Comment: @Elior can you add fiddle or any working demo as i tested same text in fiddle it worked fine for me

Comment: What do you see when you do an `inspect element` on the text? (using devtools)?

Comment: at the inspect element i see:  @test : Twitter as it should be

Answer (score 0):

i used :

```
<bdi> </bdi>
```

and it maked at the right order.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it this way using simple HTML. You don't have to mess up with any CSS as you can do with the only HTML

Example:-

```
<p>Start "&commat;" End.</p>
```